# Am I over-reacting with a downvote when the OP summarizes/elaborates the answer I provided?

Tags: discussion

Recently I answered a question by suggesting troubleshooting steps, which eventually lead the OP to solve the original question. When I clicked "Save Edits" with my last suggestion, the OP's own answer appeared. It included the conclusion that my answer lead to and some additional technical details. Feeling angry, I downvoted the OPs answer and mentioned my motivation, because the OP had not even bothered to mark my answer as useful let alone correct. On the one hand, my behavior seems helpful, because it speaks to etiquette. On the other hand, my behavior demonstrates entitlement, attachment to outcome, and reputation seeking; the OP's answer is useful, and provides additional helpful information.

[Toolbar missing when running ASP.NET core from Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784955/toolbar-missing-when-running-asp-net-core-from-visual-studio-code)

Comment: *"What seems clear is not to upvote poorly researched and unclear questions."* Yes, don't do that. *"What's less clear is whether or not to provide troubleshooting steps and educated guesses in answers."* That should be no less clear—don't do this either. If the question does not contain enough information to be definitively answered, then it should be closed (put "on hold") until such time as it is edited to include this information. If you can edit it yourself, then feel free to do so without closing. Otherwise, vote to close. "Guess" answers are not useful and cannot be proven correct.

Comment: *"My honest answer is that I up voted the question because I thought: "Oh, this looks interesting. I might answer it.""* I will admit to having that feeling on a semi-regular basis. The question covers a potentially interesting subject, something that I know a lot about and would love to answer, but it just doesn't contain enough information to actually allow me to write a high-quality answer. I have little choice but to vote to close and leave a comment begging for the requisite information to be added into the question. I rarely get a useful response, but the best you can do is try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your votes were cast against spirit of SO. Overall your original voting expectations on the Q&A pair looks way off.

Original version of "answer" did not answered the question at all and should be comment. Expecting acceptance/upvote for such answer (instead of downvote / flag for VLQ) is a stretch. Note that OP commented that information is helpful - but since there is no answer in the post it was appropriately not upvoted (no idea if it was intentional).

Downvoting answer provided by OP because "... the OP had not even bothered to mark my answer as useful let alone correct" is completely against SO spirit - votes must be cast on content of particular post (for answers it means correctness of the post and actually presence of the answer). Voting on person is not welcome.

Upvoting question because you found it interesting is plausible but it is better to vote on quality or usefulness of the question. Original version of the question did not show any research at all and deserved no votes/downvote.  If you found question *useful* then asking author in comments for more info is good start, if it did not work consider editing post with additional information based on how you've encountered/reproduced the problem.

Comment: Is a VLQ a very long question?

Comment: Thank you for the candid feedback. I appreciate it. I regret not asking meta questions earlier in my SO career. I have been doing etiquette wrong for quite some time now.